# Serialize Tweetinvi using JsonConvert.SerializeObject

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, tweetinvi

I am trying to get the following code to work, but a not implemented exception get thrown when I try to Serialize the object. It states "The method or operation is not implemented." I have tried implementing ITweet as a concrete class, but I can not go from the interface to concrete class.

```
private void SendToKinesis(ITweet tweet)
    {


        var dataAsJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tweet);
        byte[] dataAsBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataAsJson);

       //Send to Kinesis

    }
```

Complete Exception:

System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
   at Tweetinvi.Logic.JsonConverters.JsonPropertyConverterRepository.WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeConvertable(JsonWriter writer, JsonConverter converter, Object value, JsonContract contract, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObjectInternalA first chance exception of type 'System.NotImplementedException' occurred in TwitterIngestion.exe
(Object value, Type type, JsonSerializer jsonSerializer)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Object value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Object value)
   at TwitterIngestion.IngestionService.SendToKinesis(ITweet tweet) in c:\Users\sepehr500\Desktop\Work Stuff\TwitterIngestion\TwitterIngestion\IngestionTask.cs:line 104

Comment: For us to be of any help, we would need to know more.  Can you include the complete `ToString()` output of the exception, including the traceback from `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()`?

Comment: What "method or operation is not implemented"?  If you surround the call to `JsonConvert` with a `try { } catch (Exception ex) { Debug.WriteLine(ex); throw; }` you can see the complete exception.

Comment: It may be that TweetInvi does not support serialization.  Many of its classes, e.g. [`TweetDTO`](https://tweetinvi.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Development%20-%200.9.8.x/Tweetinvi.Logic/DTO/TweetDTO.cs) use the attribute `[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonPropertyConverterRepository))]`, and this class [does not implement writing](https://tweetinvi.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Development%20-%200.9.8.x/Tweetinvi.Logic/JsonConverters/JsonPropertyConverterRepository.cs) (always throws an exception).

Comment: Can you download the source, modify `JsonPropertyConverterRepository` and add `public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }`, then build and use the local version?  I'm not familiar with this library so I don't know if this is possible.

Answer (score -1):

Try following code:

```
private void SendToKinesis(ITweet tweet)
{


    var dataAsJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject<ITweet>(tweet);
    byte[] dataAsBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataAsJson);

   //Send to Kinesis

}
```

Comment: The above does not even let me compile